# how to read additional parameters in alfresco 5.1.1- aikau faceted search

Tags: alfresco-share, aikau

Custom Search UI will be populated when user selects Complex asset in the Advance search screen drop down(apart from Folders,Contents) where 12 fields will be displayed .So when user clicks search button ,need to read those values and redirect to the alfresco repo files(org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js).We have already customized these files(search.get.js,search.lib.js) existed in the repository to suit out logic and working fine in 4.2.2;As we are migrating to 511,so we need to change this logic in customized faceted-search.get.js to read these values.How to write this logic in customized facted-search.get.js?

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually possible to read those URL hash attributes in the faceted-search.get.js file because the JavaScript controller of the WebScript does not have access to that part of the URL (it only has information about the URL and the request parameters, not the hash parameters).

The hash parameters are actually handled on the client-side by the [AlfSearchList](https://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/aikau-jsdoc/AlfSearchList_.html) widget.

Maybe you could explain what you're trying to achieve so that I can suggest an alternative - i.e. the end goal for the user, not the specifics of the coding you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

We will be reading the querystring values something like below in the .get.js file.

```
function getNodeRef(){
    var queryString = page.url.getQueryString();
    var nodeRef = "NOT FOUND";
    var stringArray = queryString.split("&");
    for (var t = 0; t < stringArray.length; t++) {
        if (stringArray[t].indexOf('nodeRef=') > -1) {
            nodeRef = stringArray[t].split('=')[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (nodeRef !== "NOT FOUND") {
        nodeRef = nodeRef.replace("://", "/");
        return nodeRef;
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Node Reference is not found.");
    }
}
```

It may be help you and we will wait for Dave Drapper suggestion also.

Comment: getQueryString is for request parameters (i.e. those after the "?") and not hash parameters (i.e. those after "#")

Comment: use case is like this.
We have a Custom Search UI where 12 fields were there apart from OOTB Contents and folders in the existing Advance search screen drop down.So when user clicks search button ,need to read those values and redirect to the alfresco repo files(org/alfresco/slingshot/search/search.get.js).we have already customized these files(search.get.js,search.lib.js) existed in the repository to suit out logic and working  fine in 4.2.2;As we are migrating to 511,so we need to change this logic.How to write this logic in customized facted-search.get.js?

Comment: modified the use case description in main body as well.